# role-based methods for one web service?

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, roles

I am trying to set up a (for now) really simple web service. By simple, I mean it only has a small amount of actual work to do on the code-side. It only really has one method/function: the client sends a user login, and the service responds with an otherwise very secure detail about the user (for the purposes of this question, let's say the user's birthday).

I have a lot of questions, but for now I'm wondering:

I am considering having two versions of this method. In version one, the client can only make a generic request with no variable information. The service will respond with birthday of whoever is authenticated in the client's session. In version two, the client is allowed to query any user name (so really, anything they want) and get back either the birthday or "Nothing found", etc.

The application of offering both would be so that most developers would get the birthdate of the current user so that it can be applied to that session. To extend my example: A user logs in, the developer wants to be able to have "Happy Birthday" if it is applicable. The owners of the service/data don't want the developer's client to have any access, real or conceptual, to anything about the user, even their log in, they just want to accommodate the developer's goal, as it is really nice. The developer doesn't want to be responsible for potentially having access to anything, he just wants to be nice.

Version two is available for some user-support groups. They actually need to look up birthdates of users who call in so that they can confirm that the user's are old enough to, let's say, rent a car. They may even have to look up multiple user's to see who is most eligible out of the group to get the best deal.

So I guess the big question, finally, is whether or not these two methods can exist in the same service?

The protocol, at this point, is more likely to be SOAP-based, then RESTful, so simply having URLs that both resolve to the same service but simply offer different methods is probably not an option.

What I need, ideally, is a way to reveal operations in the WSDL based on role. Obviously the documentation given to either group would reflect only the operation appropriate for the role, but ideally the developer/client would a) not see any operations they shouldn't and b) receive the same type of response for trying to use a forbidden response as they would a non-existent one and c) most ideally, receive the former-mentioned error because for their role the operation really DOESN'T exist, not because the service took extra precaution in case the client did try (which it will, FYI, but I don't want that to be the first and only level of obfuscation).

Am I dreaming the impossible dream?

## Quick Addendum

I should have been more specific about this, I realize. When I say "role-based" I am referring to service-accounts, not user-accounts. So in my hypothetical situation above, the user-service app that would all for querying any user ID would be using one service-account with the privs to do so, not checking the role of the agent logged in to the session (which would be done to get to the app, obviously, but not to the service).

Answer (score 0):

Why not have two methods:

```
GetMyBirthday();

GetBirthday(string userName);
```

Any user can call the first method; only privileged users can call the second method.  You use role-based authorization and reject calls to the second method from unauthorized users.

I don't see why you'd want to hide methods in the WSDL based on roles.  In many cases you'll be accessing the WSDL only to build a proxy in a development environment, and won't need it at runtime.

Comment: I guess in my mind I'm trying to hide the method to lower temptation and guilt. I know that when I see something kinda neat, I want to try it out, and when I get "forbidden" I think I'm going to get in trouble for my curiosity. Plus this service has been on the backburner for my client for a very long time, specifically because security was a concern and I want to give them all the assurances imaginable.